# failed to create fsnotify watcher: too many open files

Tags: linux, kubernetes, linux-kernel

I received this error while trying to tail the log of a Kubernetes pod.

`failed to create fsnotify watcher: too many open files`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by running these commands on my server. This may be much watching every file but it will resolve your issue. You may also want to find out why there are so many files being watched.

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=2099999999
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=2099999999
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_queued_events=2099999999
```

Comment: ChatGPT says: Setting fs.inotify.max_user_watches, fs.inotify.max_user_instances, and fs.inotify.max_queued_events each to 2099999999 would theoretically reserve approximately 6008 GB (or about 6 TB) of memory, assuming an overly simplistic estimate of 1KB per watch, instance, and queued event. Setting the inotify parameters to such high values is far beyond practical requirements and could lead to system instability or prevent the system from booting correctly due to attempting to reserve excessive resources.

Answer (score 0):

Given the system defaults I had on my system (TrueNAS SCALE), after investigating with ChatGPT, I used this script to increase the values in a consistent way:

```python
# System defaults for comparison
default_max_user_instances = 128
default_max_queued_events = 16384
default_max_user_watches = 8192

# Total available memory in KB for the inotify settings
available_memory_kb = 2 * 1024 * 1024  # 2 GB in KB

# Calculate the total "weight" based on default values to keep the same ratio
total_weight = default_max_user_watches + default_max_user_watches + default_max_user_watches

# Calculate how much memory each "unit" represents
memory_per_unit = available_memory_kb / total_weight

# Allocate memory based on the original ratio
print("fs.inotify.max_user_watches =", int(memory_per_unit * default_max_user_watches))
print("fs.inotify.max_user_instances =", int(memory_per_unit * default_max_user_instances))
print("fs.inotify.max_queued_events =", int(memory_per_unit * default_max_queued_events))
```

Reasoning: The estimate of approximately 1KB of memory usage per inotify watch is a general approximation and can vary slightly depending on the architecture (32-bit vs. 64-bit) and specific kernel implementations.